# How to overlay two pdf files into one with strange characters - Python FPDF Unicode problem

Tags: python, pdf, fpdf

I'm learning Python and I'm creating a project:
I'm making a program, which gets a ready_pdf_file(with forms), creating an overlay_pdf that we gonna merge onto a final_pdf_file(with filled forms).

I have some problems with encoding, decoding probably with binaries. I've searched a lot on stackoverflow, YouTube, I spent about 5 hours - didn't find or didn't understand the solution.

Code:

```
import fpdf
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# input to fill the form
name_surname = input("Type name and surname\n")

# filenames
overlay_pdf_file_name = 'overlay_PDF.pdf'
pdf_template_file_name = 'pdf_template.pdf'
result_pdf_file_name = 'final_PDF.pdf'

# fpdf operations
pdf = fpdf.FPDF(format='letter', unit='pt')
pdf.add_page()
pdf_style = ''
pdf.set_font("Arial", style=pdf_style, size=15)


# placing a cell and filling it with the text from the input
pdf.set_xy(70, 87)
pdf.cell(150, 15, txt=name_surname, border=0, ln=0)
pdf.output(overlay_pdf_file_name)
pdf.close()


# below copied solution from GitHub: https://gist.github.com/dwayneblew/79da32727358b502f6ec

# Take the PDF you created above and overlay it on your template PDF
# Open your template PDF
pdf_template = PdfFileReader(open(pdf_template_file_name, 'rb'))
# Get the first page from the template
template_page = pdf_template.getPage(0)
# Open your overlay PDF that was created earlier
overlay_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(overlay_pdf_file_name, 'rb'))
# Merge the overlay page onto the template page
template_page.mergePage(overlay_pdf.getPage(0))
# Write the result to a new PDF file
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
output_pdf.addPage(template_page)
output_pdf.write(open(result_pdf_file_name, "wb"))
```

This results me a good filled file but only if I use normal characters.
If I use my polish characters in input like: 'ąćżł' I'm getting an error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0105' in position 50: ordinal not in range(256)

I can't understand why (probably some coding, encoding or writing in binary mode) and I can't find solution for this...
Anyone know the solution?

Comment: can u pls attach PDF files/Text inside PDF files for reference

Comment: url Broken...Pls check URL once again

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

First, I had to install (becouse I had previous, old version):

> pip install fpdf2

Then, I had to download the DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf (from link: https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/releases/download/binary/fpdf_unicode_font_pack.zip) and put it in application folder, then i needed to add 2 lines of code:

```
pdf.add_font('DejaVu', fname='DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf')
pdf.set_font('DejaVu', size=14)
```

That solved the problem. Thank you everybody for helping me.